# Scientific Reporting in Python

Tags: python, ipython, jinja2, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a scientific python project performing a bunch of computations generating a lot of data.

The problem comes when reports have to be generated from these data, with images embedded (mostly computed with matplotlib). I'd like to use a python module or tool to be able to describe the reports and "build" HTML pages for these reports (or any format supported by a browser).

I was thinking about generating an ipython notebook but I was unable to find if there is a way to do so (except creating the json but I'm doubtful about this approach).

The other way is using Sphinx a bit like the matplotlib but I am not sure how I could really fine-tune the layouts of my various pages.

The last option is to use jinja2 templates (or django-templates or any template engine working) and embed matplotlib code inside.

I know it's vague but was unable to find any kind of reference.

Comment: I guess you'll have to style your own HTML pages, since there is no module out of the box…

Comment: It does appear you can save and import Python files for an ipython notebook, instead of JSON. Then again, an ipython notebook would contain all the commands and generate all the files (again), so for a proper report, may not be the best suitable option.

Comment: @Evert yep this is finally what I thought.

Comment: @septi I just wanted a confirmation. thx.

Answer (score 5):

nbconvert has been merged into IPython itself, so please do not use the standalone version anymore. It is now fully template base so you can change things from just tweeking the css, fully re-wrote your templates, or just overwrite the current part of templates you want.

Notebook format is a pure json file, is takes ~20 lines to write a program that loop through it and re-run the codecell. That plus command line argument it is not hard to write a notebook, make it a 'template' notebook and run it on multiple dataset without opening a browser.

Some resources :

[programatically run nbconvert](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/Carreau/posts/master/06-NBconvert-Doc-Draft.ipynb), and run a notebook [headless (first link)](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Cookbook:-Notebook-utilities)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to work in ipython notebook and then use [nbconvert](https://github.com/ipython/nbconvert)

Currently, this is it's own utility, that already works (albeit with some installation hurdles, but working) but it is currently being implemented directly into the ipython notebook machinery, which I believe should be released in autumn, or so.

The goal is (and Fernando Perez has demonstrated that this works), that a notebook becomes a fully documented, image containing pdf-document after the conversion.

Comment: That's a nice tool, but still I have to generate the notebook somehow right ?

Comment: Well, the notebook is your actual data analysis tool, that's why it is so handy that it can be converted to a report. Even before you have the definitive Python scripts to do the analysis you would try out pieces of that code inside your notebook. Once you have found working code pieces, you would copy them into a more complete Python script that you then can call from the notebook, including matplotlib plotting commands that are displayed inside the notebook as well (see ericmjl's answer how to start it for that). That way your notebook get's smaller and smaller while your tools grow.

Comment: ... but your explorative character of the notebook when you digged through the data never gets lost and that's something good to report on.

Comment: I know I use notebooks a lot, but I don't know how I could tweak the page layout to fit what I want.

Comment: nbconvert has been merged into IPython-dev, it is not standalone anymore.

Comment: @Matt hence my comment in my 2nd paragraph. LB, you never mentioned before that the _style_ is what you have a problem with? I believe, theme-ing is supported by nbconvert.

Comment: Yes, what I was meaning, is "Do not use the standalone version, it does not exist anymore, you will have to use IPython dev.". Otherwise dead line for IPython 1.0 is in a week. (yes we'll be late)

Comment: ohhh! Didn't know it was so soon and didn't know it was advised to not use the stand-alone, thanks! Can't wait for 1.0, using dev already for quite some time. Especially love that the width now scales with browser window width.

Answer (score 1):

Using the inline-modus of ipython notebook,

> ipython notebook --pylab inline

you can execute your matplotlib-scripts in a browser interactively (thus generating your plots). Then go to

> File -> Print View (in the notebook-menu, NOT the browser menu)

and save the generated html-File (via the browser menu). This will include all the plots you generated before as well as the python code. Of course, you cannot modify these html-Files anymore without the notebook-server in the background.
Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I just found this old question and want to add [`PWeave`](http://mpastell.com/pweave/) to the list, which is perfectly suited to generate reports from python code / jupyter notebooks. I use it to share my work with colleagues that aren't invested with programming alot.

It also integrates into Spyder, THE scientific IDE for python, using the [`spyder-reports`](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-reports) module.